# Rendering/Editing different data objects on one advancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4

I've been struggling with this for quite a while now. 
The dataProvider for my grid contains several objects. Some of which have a Number value, and some Boolean values under field 'value' (other fields are used in other columns).

I would like to be able to render differently for each data-type, i.e. have a checkBox for booleans, and a label for numbers. Furthermore, I would like to be able to edit these fields differently, unchecking the checkbox for booleans, and using a numericStepper for Numbers.

Any suggestions?

Just FYI, I decided to go with AdvancedDataGrid, to take advantage of the styleFunction property, nothing more..

Tried to used spark-states, which didn't seem to work as I'm using an AdvancedDataGrid. I'm not sure what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this behavior using ItemRenderes and ItemEditors.

you can render out a checkbox if the type of the value is Boolean, and if it's something else you can render out a textInput.

Comment: That was my initial approach, but combined, my custom editor, and my custom renderer, (both data-dependant) didn't seem to work. I thought maybe there's a better approach to this that I'm not aware of.

Comment: post some code here maybe because this approach should definitely work. it works for me in more then one occasion so I am pretty sure this is the way to go.